iOS Does Not Offer Import Option for Downloaded VCF File from FlutterFlow Web App
I have a custom function in FlutterFlow that downloads a VCF file from the web part of my application. This file can be imported into contacts on Android devices. However, on iOS, the downloaded file does not offer the option to import or add it to the contacts.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as thehttp;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

Future<String> saveContact(ProfileStruct profile, List<String> links) async {
  final newContact = Contact()
    ..displayName = profile.name
    ..name.first = profile.name
    ..name.last = profile.familyName
    ..organizations = [
      Organization(company: profile.company, jobDescription: profile.job)
    ]
    ..addresses = [Address(profile.stringAdresse)]
    ..phones = profile.phones.map((number) => Phone(number.value)).toList()
    ..emails = profile.emails.map((mail) => Email(mail.value)).toList()
    ..websites = links.map((link) => Website(link)).toList()
    ..notes = [Note(profile.bio)];

  try {
    final imageResponse = await thehttp.get(Uri.parse(profile.image));
    final imageBytes = imageResponse.bodyBytes;
    newContact.photo = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);
  } catch (e) {}

  String vCard = newContact.toVCard();
  final fileBytes = utf8.encode(vCard);
  final blob = html.Blob([fileBytes]);
  final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
  final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: url);
  anchor.download = 'contact.vcf';
  html.document.body!.append(anchor);
  anchor.click();
  html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
  anchor.remove();

  return vCard;
}


This function works perfectly on Android, but on iOS, the downloaded VCF file does not provide the option to import it into the contacts. The function is executed from the web part of my FlutterFlow application. How can I ensure the VCF file can be imported on iOS devices as well?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!
